# what is the way of accessing app outer folder files to render in template of play framework 2.6.x?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Though in dev mode it is possible to upload files by ref.move to() method  in public folder or any app folder in play framework and rendering that file by AssetsFinder 's path() method. But in prod mode uploading file in public folder or app folder is not allowed. In this case what I can do to access the app outer folder files and what will be the actual rendering method to render the file (images) in template? 
Looking for a detail solution....

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, Action, AnyContent, ControllerComponents}



@Singleton
class ImageServerController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def serveImages(imageName:String): Action[AnyContent] = Assets.versioned("/tmp/images",imageName)




}
```

config file

```
GET     /test                       controllers.TestController.test    
GET     /dynamicassets/*file                       controllers.ImageServerController.serveImages(file)
```

accessing views

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, Action, AnyContent, ControllerComponents}

@Singleton
class TestController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit assetsFinder: AssetsFinder)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def test:Action[AnyContent]=Action{

    Ok(views.html.testview("hotelapp.jpeg"))
  }

}
```

here view

```
@(fileName:String)



    <img src="@routes.ImageServerController.serveImages(fileName)">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, 
We need to use **Streaming HTTP responses** to do this.

Here is the documentation....
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaStream

my controller code will be

```
 package controllers

import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.http.HttpEntity
import play.api.mvc._



@Singleton
class ImageServerController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit assetsFinder: AssetsFinder)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {



  def serveImages(imageName:String):Action[AnyContent] = Action {

    val file = new java.io.File("/tmp/images/"+imageName)
    val path: java.nio.file.Path = file.toPath
    val source: Source[ByteString, _] = FileIO.fromPath(path)

    Result(
      header = ResponseHeader(200, Map.empty),
      body = HttpEntity.Streamed(source, None, Some("image/jpeg"))
    )
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options :

1) After the upload of the file, you move it to a folder (for example /uploads) created in your app directory. Then you serve these images via Apache which is more adapted than play to serve assets.

You need to have Apache as a reverse proxy of your application and configure a url to serve assets instead or redirecting to your application.

2) You also move the file to a folder (/uploads) and then you create a route in you application

```
GET /img/:name controllers.MyController.serveImage(name: String)
```

and in your controller :

```
public Result serveImage(String name) {
    String path = "uploads/" + name;
    return ok(new File(path));
}
```

The benefit of 2) is that you can manage authorisations when serving the file depending on the user.